# Angular 6 *ngFor directive not working

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I just created a new project after upgrading my cli to v6 and added the dashboard layout using the Angular Material util.

I was just messing around and realized that ngFor was not working for me.

I ensured that the CommonModule was being imported, I checked if other directives were working like `*ngIf`. Am I doing something wrong or is something broken after updating?

Test Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  topics: ['C','C#']

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Html:

```
<div>
  <p>Topics</p>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let topic of topics">{{topic}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I just placed my app-test component inside the cards built by the Dashboard quickstart, here is what renders.

Screenshot:
[image]

Ng --Version:
[image]

Comment: any css you have for that li? Or is there no css?

Comment: No css it created the css file but I didn't apply anything to it

Comment: is your console outputting something? like an error I mean..

Comment: No that is the confusing part there are no errors in the chrome debugger.

Comment: `topics: ['C','C#']` -> `:` should be `=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declared the variable but you are not initialize it. just try this

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    topics: [] = ['C','C#']

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

### Explanation:

`topics:  ['C','C#']` in this code how  typescript handle it like . `['C','C#']` is a datatype of `topics` variable instead of assigning value for that variable. so you should provide the data as like

`topics :[]= ['C','C#']`

Comment: Well it's 4:36 am here and I realize how dumb of a mistake this was because I am half asleep. Thanks for catching this.

Comment: its not wrong. note that you should use `=` to assign value, not `:`.

Comment: @deezg Yeah I see that I am just half asleep apparently, thanks for spotting that.

Comment: @deezg Updated .

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring the type of **topics** instead of initializing it

try

> Test Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  topics: string[]

  constructor() { 
      this.topics=['C','C#'];
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```